# Login no longer redirects back to the page I was on before logging in with Google

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, google-openid, redirection

This has been annoying me for a little while now, but I kept assuming I'd clicked the wrong thing...

Used to be, if you were somewhere on a site - say, viewing a question - and clicked "login", you'd be directed through the login process *and then brought back to the question after successfully authenticating.*

Now, I'm brought to the home page.

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a browser session and visit a site on which you're not logged in.
2. Open a question.
3. Click "login" in the top bar.
4. Click "Log in using Google" and log into the site using your Google account.
5. Note that you're now viewing the home page rather than the question you opened in Step #2.

#### Notes:

I've tested this using both Chrome 36 and Firefox 31 on Windows 8.1. The Stack Exchange and Facebook providers work as designed, but logging in with Google breaks as described above.

Comment: Strange - if I am on a child-meta question and log in, I do get redirected back to the question.

Comment: @Oded there's a "newreg" query string variable now, pretty sure it's something new so likely the cause for losing the context.

Comment: @shog9, I can't repro it the way you describe.  I *do* hit this all the time if I hit "signup", then toggle to login when I realize my mistake- *that* always sends me back to the home page, whether I do it from the top bar or the screen that pops up when I try to vote or whatever.

Comment: I did some further testing, @Jaydles - it appears this behavior only breaks when using Google to authenticate.

Comment: Reproduced with Stack Exchange OpenID.

Comment: Looking into this... the newreg query string's been around a while... So either it's unrelated or this has been broken a while. :)

Comment: FWIW, it's quite possible this has been bothering me more lately because autologin stopped working - haven't had time to dig into that yet though.

Comment: @Shog9 [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238220/why-is-global-auth-disabled) might explain why auto-login stopped working

Comment: Oh good, now I don't *have* to dig into it. Thanks @Mad

Comment: @Shog9 Now you only have to spin the wheel of blame ;-)

Comment: @Anna well, Shog did say "This has been annoying me for a little while now" so most likely it's the second option.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [Both. Both. Both. Both is good.](http://37.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m4vde5Hkcf1r5jtugo1_500.gif) Newregkey is completely unrelated, and this has been broken since we switched to Google's OAuth2 flow which was a while back. ;)

Comment: Reproduced in Safari 6.1 on Mac OS 10.8, Safari 7 on Mac OS 10.9, Mobile Safari on iOS 7.

Comment: @AnnaLear OK, guess I should guess less. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The real question here is... why do you hate the homepage, bro?

But seriously, we missed a query string parameter during the switch over to Google's OAuth2 flow. Fix deployed. Enjoy. :)