# Change login to use a dialog box rather than a separate web page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, login, sign-up

[image]Stack Exchange websites redirect the user to another page for logging in or signing up. Being frank, I don't like this.

The website [Flipkart](http://flipkart.com) does this a better way. At the upper right of the page, there's two links: one for 'Login' and another for 'Signup'. If we click either of them, a dialog box appears to log in, not another web page. It would be nice if Stack Exchange implemented this.

Comment: Those are an annoying way to log in

Comment: No one is "angry" with you. People will (should) simply vote on the merits of your feature request. Right now, it seems that most people don't think it's a good idea. In any event, your pre-amble is unnecessary noise.

Comment: If I click the login with Google option it still redirects me to another page...

Comment: @animuson it is usual and for security.

Comment: @random what do you mean by 'those'? My suggestion?

Comment: What else is being suggested here?

Comment: While I am answering a question or ask a question, I found that and I am not logged in, after logging in, the website redirects me to the home page. So I have to start it from one.

Comment: @RogUE So it's acceptable for them to do that but not us? Stack Exchange *only* uses third-party providers for login. They don't have their own system that they could build a popup-box login like that.

Comment: @RogUE what you experience should not happen. Clicking login should redirect you back to the question you were visiting. [There was a bug that got fixed not long ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238218/login-no-longer-redirects-back-to-the-page-i-was-on-before-logging-in-with-goog), maybe it returned.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know about the bug, but it happened so. I just tried it now, it happens while answering a question.

Comment: What is the difficulty in the current system ?

Answer (score 2):

While there is some annoyance factor to going via the login page it does have the advantage that it is unlikely to be interfered with by pop-up blockers and will work on just about any browser - not all browsers support pop-ups.  Other such methods rely on java/JavaScript, etc., which again some browsers do not support and some/many users have disabled for security reasons.

To work around the scenario of I would like to comment/vote/whatever on the page that I am on and do not wish to have to find it again after logging on you can - in many browsers - right click on the login link and select open in new tab, login on the new tab and then go to the original and refresh (F5) - you will find that you are still on the same page but now you are logged in.

Comment: Of-course, the refreshing way will work fine, but, as far as flipkart.com is concerned, there's no pop-ups for logging-in.

Comment: @RogUE - The login frame that I see when I click on login on flipkart sure looks like some sort of pop-up to me!

Comment: I think pop-ups are a separate window(not in the tab which one is working) which open while clicking a link. If the login frame in flipkart is a pop-up, why my AdBlock doesn't block it?

Comment: You say that this is for the convenience of all users( especially those have disabled java scripts and pop-ups), then why stack exchange says that "Stack exchange best works with java script enabled"?

Comment: Works __best__ but if JavaScript is disabled flipkart doesn't work.  Note that some of us access SO from within corporate environments where our browsers security settings are out of our hands.

Comment: Flipkart will work if the java script is disabled. If you have disabled java and click login in Flipkart, it takes yout o another page to log in. Which means, flipkart too works great with java script enabled.

Comment: Stack exchange may implement this, easy way for those who have enabled JS and the annoying way for those who have disabled JS.

Comment: @RogUE - why would AdBlock block the login popup? It is supposed to block _ads_, not popups.

Answer (score 2):

The login method employed by flipkart is vulnerable to MITM attacks.

The form/page is **not** served over HTTPS, thus, content can be injected into the page by **anyone** between yourself and flipkart. Not as secure as it probably should be. (see details on [this blog post](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/05/your-login-form-posts-to-https-but-you.html) by Troy Hunt).

Our login forms are *always* served over HTTPS. Making them popups will only make them *less* secure when they come up on pages served as HTTP.

Arguably, we don't deal with money on the Stack Exchange Q&A sites, but we *do* take username/password pair for the Stack Exchange OpenId provider, that can be used anywhere an OpenId is accepted - so making the form *less* secure is not an option.

This is a minor annoyance to you, but imagine the annoyance if your username and password were harvested by a malicious third party and used for nefarious deeds.

Comment: `I think pop-ups are a separate window(not in the tab which one is working) which open while clicking a link. If the login frame in flipkart is a pop-up, why my AdBlock doesn't block it? ` as per Rogues comment, Is this true ?

Comment: @Javageek - doesn't matter if the page they come from is served over HTTP. You have no idea if that's the actual content that flipkart meant to send you.